# Activity switching wont keep the state of the view alive even using saveinstancestate() why?

Tags: android

Salam

i just started working on android(beginner). Im stuck in the activity state complexity. I created two activitys(activity1 and activity2). wen i move from the activity1 to 2  and then back to activity1 using a button(back of activity)the values(states) of the views are not restored. here is the code..

### ACTIVITY1

```
public class activity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String txt;
    EditText etxt;
    TextView tv;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate() : " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn_cont = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        etxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxt);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btn_cont.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View click) {
        txt = etxt.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        tv.setText(txt);
    }
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle sis){
        sis.putString("ist arg", "sec arg");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ActivitySaveIns", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onSaveInstanceState(sis);
    }
}
```

### ACTIVITY2

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button btn_back;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act2);
        btn_back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,activity1.class);
        startActivity(intent2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what your doing:

1. Start `Activity1`
2. Start `Activity2`
3. Start [another instance of] `Activity1`

So after you have pressed the 'back' button [you should just let the hardware back button do the job!], you end up with *three* activities.

If you want to keep a back button like that, instead of creating a new instance just call `onBackButtonPressed()` which will close the current Activity (and take you back to the original one).

Comment: thanx alot that was so helpful. .  i used the onresume() to the state of the activity1.

Comment: does it mean that i hav to do all the coding in the onresume() to restore the views values??

Comment: If you are going back to the same activity (i.e. when you press back), then you don't have to do any work to restore the values. If you want to pass values back, look into startActivityForResult(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities